# When is a Brieskorn manifold diffeomorphic to an exotic sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-topology

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2459365/brieskorn-manifold-diffeomorphic-to-the-sphere) is a related question but what I'm asking here is more general. I find the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brieskorn_manifold) on Brieskorn manifolds a bit vague. The manifolds are defined to be the intersection of a "small sphere" centered at the origin with the variety
$$x_1^{k_1}+...+x_n^{k_n}=0$$
After a bit of looking around on this website and overflow I found out that the $x_i$ are complex. My question is: what constraints on $k_i$ must there be and how "small" must the sphere with which we intersect the variety be for the Brieskorn manifold to be diffeomeophic to an exotic sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical condition is that the sphere intersects transversally your variety, see the first pages of the book "Singular points of complex hypersurfaces" by J. Milnor. I think any sphere should do in your special case.

The $k_i$ should be all integers $\geq 2$, else you just get a usual sphere. Indeed locally you can assume your variety is given by say $z_1 = 0$ so the intersection $S \cap \{z_0 = 0\}$ is the sphere $|z_1|^2 + \dots + |z_n|^2 = 1$.

The simplest non trivial example is the cusp $y^2 = x^3$. Here, the Brieskorn sphere will be a circle, however embedded as a knot in a torus. More precisely let us look a the intersection of the curve with a sphere of radius $\varepsilon > 0$. We obtain the equation $|x|^2 + |y|^2 = \varepsilon, y^2 = x^3$. From this, it's easy to see that the modulus of $x$ and $y$ should be constant, say $\xi(\varepsilon)$ for $x$ and $\eta(\varepsilon) $ for $y$. This is exactly the equation of a torus. But in fact, the equation $y^2 = x^3$ tells us that $3\theta(y) = 2\theta(x)$. This means exactly that you get a torus knot of type $(3,2)$ inside a torus !

More generally, for small $\varepsilon$ let $X_{\varepsilon} = X \cap S_{\varepsilon}$ and $X_{\leq \varepsilon} = X \cap \overline B(0, \varepsilon)$. There is an homeomorphism of pair $(X_{\leq \varepsilon}, X_{\varepsilon} ) \cong (Cone (X_{\varepsilon}), X_{\varepsilon})$ ! This is a very stricking theorem. In particular the full topology of a neighorhood of a singular point is contained in the link $X_{\varepsilon}$. In the previous case it holds for any $\varepsilon > 0$ by construction, and I think the same should holds for  the singularities you mentioned.